# ContextualVersionConflict using BigQuery in AI-Platform-Notebooks

Tags: python, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am trying to use BigQuery in AI-Platform-Notebooks, but I am running into a ContextualVersionConflict.
In this toy example, I am trying to pull two columns worth of data from the BigQuery database entitled bgt_all, in the project job2vec.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

aaa="""

SELECT BGTJobId, soc6 FROM `job2vec.bq_bgt_storage.bgt_all` LIMIT 100
"""
df = client.query(aaa).to_dataframe()
df.head()
```

which returns

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ContextualVersionConflict                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-7bdfe216bcc8> in <module>
      7 SELECT BGTJobId, soc6 FROM `job2vec.bq_bgt_storage.bgt_all` LIMIT 100
      8 """
----> 9 df = client.query(aaa).to_dataframe()
     10 df.head()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py in to_dataframe(self, bqstorage_client, dtypes, progress_bar_type, create_bqstorage_client, date_as_object)
   3381             progress_bar_type=progress_bar_type,
   3382             create_bqstorage_client=create_bqstorage_client,
-> 3383             date_as_object=date_as_object,
   3384         )
   3385 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py in to_dataframe(self, bqstorage_client, dtypes, progress_bar_type, create_bqstorage_client, date_as_object)
   1725                 progress_bar_type=progress_bar_type,
   1726                 bqstorage_client=bqstorage_client,
-> 1727                 create_bqstorage_client=create_bqstorage_client,
   1728             )
   1729             df = record_batch.to_pandas(date_as_object=date_as_object)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py in to_arrow(self, progress_bar_type, bqstorage_client, create_bqstorage_client)
   1535         owns_bqstorage_client = False
   1536         if not bqstorage_client and create_bqstorage_client:
-> 1537             bqstorage_client = self.client._create_bqstorage_client()
   1538             owns_bqstorage_client = bqstorage_client is not None
   1539 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py in _create_bqstorage_client(self)
    402         """
    403         try:
--> 404             from google.cloud import bigquery_storage_v1
    405         except ImportError:
    406             warnings.warn(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery_storage_v1/__init__.py in <module>
     20 
     21 __version__ = pkg_resources.get_distribution(
---> 22     "google-cloud-bigquery-storage"
     23 ).version  # noqa
     24 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in get_distribution(dist)
    478         dist = Requirement.parse(dist)
    479     if isinstance(dist, Requirement):
--> 480         dist = get_provider(dist)
    481     if not isinstance(dist, Distribution):
    482         raise TypeError("Expected string, Requirement, or Distribution", dist)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in get_provider(moduleOrReq)
    354     """Return an IResourceProvider for the named module or requirement"""
    355     if isinstance(moduleOrReq, Requirement):
--> 356         return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
    357     try:
    358         module = sys.modules[moduleOrReq]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in require(self, *requirements)
    897         included, even if they were already activated in this working set.
    898         """
--> 899         needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
    900 
    901         for dist in needed:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in resolve(self, requirements, env, installer, replace_conflicting, extras)
    788                 # Oops, the "best" so far conflicts with a dependency
    789                 dependent_req = required_by[req]
--> 790                 raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
    791 
    792             # push the new requirements onto the stack

ContextualVersionConflict: (google-api-core 1.22.1 (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.22.2'), {'google-cloud-bigquery-storage'})
```

This is odd because when I run
!pip install google-api-core --upgrade
it shows it is 1.24.1 so I don't quite understand why.

EDITED: The following appears when I type !conda list | grep google

```
google-api-core-grpcio-gcp 1.16.0                        1    conda-forge
google-api-python-client  1.9.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
google-apitools           0.5.31                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth               1.24.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-httplib2      0.0.3                      py_3    conda-forge
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.1                      py_2    conda-forge
google-cloud-bigquery     1.24.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-bigquery-storage 2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-bigtable     1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-core         1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-dataproc     1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-datastore    1.7.4                    pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-dlp          0.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-firestore    1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-kms          1.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-language     1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-logging      1.15.1                   pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-pubsub       1.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-scheduler    1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-spanner      1.17.1                   pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-speech       1.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-storage      1.30.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-tasks        1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-translate    2.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-videointelligence 1.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-vision       0.42.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-crc32c             0.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
google-pasta              0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
google-resumable-media    0.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
googleapis-common-protos  1.51.0           py37hc8dfbb8_2    conda-forge
grpc-google-iam-v1        0.12.3                   pypi_0    pypi
```

Comment: what do you get when you run `!conda list | grep google`

Comment: I tried same command  and worked fine (different table) using latest DLVM https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/release-notes#November_12_2020, I fixed a bug related to google-api-core

Comment: @gogasca Just added the output when typing !conda list | grep google. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Seems to be you are using an older version of AI Platform notebooks where we pinned "google-api-core-grpcio-gcp" to 1.16, this seems to conflict with google-cloud-bigquery-storage, which is expecting a version 1.22 or greater. https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/changelog.html in a brand new Notebook I get: ```google-api-core           1.22.4             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
google-api-core-grpcio-gcp 1.22.2               hc8dfbb8_0    conda-forge``` is it possible to migrate to a new notebook or If using Notebooks API we also provide an upgrade endpoint.

Comment: Can you run the following command and check if it works after it `pip install --upgrade pandas-gbq 'google-cloud-bigquery[bqstorage,pandas]'`. In addition, I was able to run a the following command without any error: `df = pandas.read_gbq(sql, dialect='standard') \\ project_id = 'project-id' \\ df = pandas.read_gbq(sql, project_id=project_id, dialect='standard') \\
df.head()` . Did it work for you? *Attention that each \\  represents just a new line and sql is your query.*

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes that did it, thank you!! It worked under the first iteration too (without needing the project_id).

Comment: @sbecon, in order to further contribute to the community, I will post the answer based o my last comment. I would appreciate if you could accept and upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to further contribute to the community I am posting the answer based on my comment above.

Firstly, you should try to upgrade the packages using the command:

`pip install --upgrade pandas-gbq 'google-cloud-bigquery[bqstorage,pandas]'`

Then, instead of using the *to_dataframe()* method you can use the [read_gbq()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_gbq.html), which loads data from BigQuery using the environment's default project, as follows:

```
import pandas

sql = """
    SELECT name
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`
    WHERE state = 'TX'
    LIMIT 100
"""

# Run a Standard SQL query using the environment's default project
df = pandas.read_gbq(sql, dialect='standard')

# Run a Standard SQL query with the project set explicitly
project_id = 'your-project-id'
df = pandas.read_gbq(sql, project_id=project_id, dialect='standard')
```

*The above code was taken from the documentation, [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration#standard-sql-query).*

Answer (score 1):

In Deep Learning VM image [version 50](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/release-notes#June_23_2020) the library **google-api-core-grpcio-gcp** was pinned to version 1.16 because of a library [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/python-api-core/issues/47).

Later this library seems to conflict with **google-cloud-bigquery-storage**, which is expecting a more recent version ([1.22](http://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/changelog.html) or greater).  If you start using Deep Learning VM 59+ [version](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/release-notes#November_12_2020) where pin was removed you should not see this issue:

```
google-api-core           1.22.4             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge 
google-api-core-grpcio-gcp 1.22.2               hc8dfbb8_0    conda-forge
```

You can create a brand new [notebook](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/registering-legacy-notebooks#migrate-to-new-instance) or If using Notebooks API we also provide an [upgrade](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.instances/upgrade) endpoint which you can use to upgrade to latest DLVM version.